# How to hide html output files when using pug in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pug

How do i disable seeing the .html files when there is a pug file in visual studio code? Right now in my file explorer on the left i see both the .html and the .pug files.

Comment: You could put your Pug and HTML files in different directories.

Comment: Not really the solution i am looking for - there is a piece of code that can be added to vscode that does this in configuration for file types. I just cannot find it. Used to be published somewhere when pug was called jade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to this after some searching. Open .vscode folder and open the settings file and add the following code snippet:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/*.html": { "when": "$(basename).pug"},
}
```

Html files will now be hidden. You can do this for other file types as well.

I couldnt find a way to do this through the settings editor in the app, had to do this manually with the config files.